# C# - Detecting Keydown and KeyUp events in the background

Tags: c#, hook

I’ve been trying to create an console application which runs in the background detecting any key ups and keydown events, I’ve seen some threads on global key hooks however, I’m unable to make it detect key ups and key downs rather then key presses.

I’d like some advice on how to go about it, any help is valued and appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution using GetAsyncKeyState()